# Load a pickle model to predict another dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, logistic-regression

I have two datasets. First one is train , another one is test. First of all , I use LogisticRegression to train my model and saved like ;

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

X = df[['Age', 'Gender']]
y = df['Race']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)


ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
ohe.fit(X_train)
X_train_ohe = ohe.transform(X_train).toarray()
ohe_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_ohe, columns=ohe.get_feature_names(X_train.columns))
clf= LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
clf.fit(X_train_ohe, y_train.values.ravel())
X_test_ohe = ohe.transform(X_test)
y_preds = clf.predict(X_test_ohe)


print(" Logistic Regression ")
print ("Logistic Regression : ",accuracy_score(y_test, y_preds))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_preds)) 



model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)


pickle.dump(model,open('model.pkl','wb'))
```

At this step , I want to create a new python file and read test.csv file. However , the test.csv has NaN values in 'Race' header. I can fill NaN values with 0 in test.csv but what I have to do after this step? I have to predict Race values using with loaded model. I tried code block like :

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['Race']=df['Race'].replace(['NaN'], '0')
X = df[['Age', 'Gender']]


model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
```

Comment: Hello, is your model load and you have to predict ? or your model is not load yet ?

Comment: Hi @HarshParekh , my model loaded. Just I have to predict test.csv 'Race' header , which are NaN.

Comment: Hi, then just use that model and pass your X (dataframe) like these 
model.predict(X) and don't pass your Y col in it.

Comment: Hi have you closed your file?

Comment: @VibhavSurve not yet sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
predictions=model.predict(df.drop('Race',axis=1))
print(predictions)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However , there is some issue exist. So , my 'Race' variable has values 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,5 in data.csv but on the predictions only values 0 and 1 appear.