# How to predict from another file in regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I want to predict sale price of houses .I have a `train.csv` file with details of more than 1400 houses along with sale price which is used to train and test the data. And there is a `test.csv` file which includes details of many houses without sale price which we want to predict. I trained and tested the data and got a `r2score` of above 0.9 . But I don't know how to predict the sale price from another file `test.csv`.

````py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
categorical_cols =['MSZoning','Street','Alley','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope','Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtQual','BsmtCond','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1','BsmtFinType2','Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','Electrical','KitchenQual','Functional','FireplaceQu','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','PoolQC','Fence','MiscFeature','SaleType','SaleCondition']
le = LabelEncoder()
data[categorical_cols] = data[categorical_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
array_hot_encoded = ohe.fit_transform(data[categorical_cols])
data_hot_encoded = pd.DataFrame(array_hot_encoded, index=data.index)
data_other_cols = data.drop(columns=categorical_cols)
data_out = pd.concat([data_hot_encoded, data_other_cols], axis=1)
data_out.drop(['Id'], axis=1)
data_out=data_out.fillna(method="bfill")
data_out=data_out.dropna()
sale_price=['SalePrice']
sale = pd.DataFrame(sale_price)
dX=data_out.drop(columns=sale)
dy=data_out.iloc[:,-1]
dX=scale(dX)
dy=scale(dy)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dX, dy, test_size = 0.2)
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

df_preds = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test.squeeze(), 'Predicted': y_pred.squeeze()})
print(df_preds)

print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred))```
````

Answer (score 1):

As you have two datasets, one which you are training model `train.csv` and other dataset where you are testing model `test.csv`.

Save model and hyperparameters using `pickle` file while training model on `train.csv`. A pickle file is generated, store it in your device.

While testing model on `test.csv`, load `pickle` file and `test.csv` dataset and apply model stored in `pickle` file.

Code- Saving pickle file and applying it on test dataset

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pickle.dump(model,open('model.pkl','wb'))

#Loading pickle file
model=pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))
#Loading test.csv dataset
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
#Predict sales based on multiple columns in dataset
df['sales']=model.predict(df[['MSZoning','Street','Alley','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope','Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtQual','BsmtCond','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1','BsmtFinType2','Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','Electrical','KitchenQual','Functional','FireplaceQu','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','PoolQC','Fence','MiscFeature','SaleType','SaleCondition''MSZoning','Street','Alley','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope','Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtQual','BsmtCond','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1','BsmtFinType2','Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','Electrical','KitchenQual','Functional','FireplaceQu','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','PoolQC','Fence','MiscFeature','SaleType','SaleCondition']])
print(df['sales'])
```

Ref link- [Load a pickle model to predict another dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782782/load-a-pickle-model-to-predict-another-dataset)

https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/machine-learning/how-to-save-and-load-machine-learning-models-using-pickle